# View or Download image on click of image/filename

Tags: laravel-5

I followed a couple of tutorial about batch image upload using laravel but they all talk about displaying images as thumbnails which it is not what i want to achieve. I want to view stored image filenames and also a user be able to download the saved images.

Controller

```
class Controller_Name extends Controller {
//index
  public function index() {
    $variable = Model::all();
    return view('your.view', compact('variable'));
  }

//uploading images to DB
public function upload() {
    // getting all of the post data
    //$file = array('image' => Request::file('image'));
    $file = Input::file('images');

    //counting all selected images
    $file_count = count($file);
    $uploadcount = 0;

    // setting up rules
    foreach($file as $file) {
      $rules = array('form' => 'required');

      // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
      $validator = Validator::make(array ('form'=>$file), $rules);


      if ($validator->passes())
      {
        $destinationPath = 'path/to/upload/folder';
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $uploadcount ++;

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $entry = new Model;
        $entry->format = $file->getClientMimeType();
        $entry->filename = $filename;
        $entry->save();
      }
    }

    if($uploadcount == $file_count)
    {
      Session::flash('message', 'Uploaded successfully');
    }
    else {
      return Redirect::to('your/view')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }
  }
```

I have a table that display image names stored in db and now i want a corresponding image to show or be downloaded when a user clicks on it or view button.

```
<!-->displaying images filenames in tabular view<--><thead>
        <tr>
        <th >#</th>
        <th >Image Name</th>
        <th >File Format</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>

      @foreach( $variable_declared_in_download_function as $some_random_variable)                                                     <tr>
    <td class="text-left">{{ asset('img/') }}></td>                                    <td class="text-left">{{ $jan2017->format}}</td>                                    
    <td>buttons here (delete/download)</td>
    </tr>                                                                   @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
        @endsection
```

Anyone out there who can help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well this is close enough to what i wanted to achieve. I included a download button which picks the selected image and downloads it.
Here is the remodeled Controller

```
    Use DB;
class controller_name extends controller{
//index function goes here

//created a new function to download images for viewing 
public function download(){
$download=DB::table('table_name')->get();
return view('path.to.view',compact('download'));
```

And the route i used is this

```
Route::get('download', 'Controller_Name@download');
```

In my index.blade.php

this is how i changed the structuring

```
   <td>
     <a href="path/to/where/your/app/stores/uploaded/images{{$download->filename}}" 
download = "{{$download->filename}}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View                                     </button>
</a>
```

with that, i can now download and view the image saved in the DB.

Thanks to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlnackyPJPY